# Unable to simplify a list to an array in R using the simplify2array function?

Tags: r

I currently have a list in `R` I would like to simplify into an array. For some reason, every time I apply `simplify2array` to the list, it still comes back as a list. For example:

```
> class(simplify2array(A.List))
[1] "list"
```

ss the result of what happens. I tried to create a small reproducible example, but the best I could come up with was the original list that gave me problems, which I have linked here:

https://github.com/thestatcoder/Data/raw/master/A.List.RData

I am unable to understand why the list is not able to be transformed to an array. I have looked through everything and am at a complete loss. Is there any reasoning here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `abind()`.

```
# load(url("https://github.com/thestatcoder/Data/raw/master/A.List.RData"))

library(abind)
A.Array <- do.call(abind, A.List)

> class(A.Array)
[1] "array"
```